# Auto cc addresses on inbound emails from certain addresses in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

I am wanting to automatically add a cc address to any inbound emails that come from a specific address (which is external to the company).

I've had a quick look into Transport rules however I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Is anybody able to provide me with some assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport rules are you only option, but adding in a CC isn't possible. The only options you have are to include a BCC or copy the message to another recipient.